# Value of input is set but not visible Kendo Grid

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I'm building a custom kendo grid, in which I need to validate some special chars when editing a row. 
I'm at the point where I can get the value of the input and then remove all non-accepted chars and set the new string to the input.val(), in the browser console the value is set but in the grid this chars are stil visible.
I spent some research trying to find a text() property but got no luck, any ideas would be appreciated.

Here is where I set the value to the same input:

```
var strFinal='';
var str = input.val().split('');
for (var x = 0; x < str.length; x++) {
if (str[x] == ' ' || str[x] == 'ñ' || str[x] == 'Ñ' || str[x] == '.' || (str[x] >= '0' && str[x] <= '9') || (str[x] >= 'A' && str[x] <= 'Z') || (str[x] >= 'a' && str[x] <= 'z')) {
strFinal += str[x];
 }};
 input.val(strFinal);
 console.log(input);
 return true;
```

Here the console log where I see the value but in the grid the text remains.

[console log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2DyyG.png)

[grid view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bvVkv.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll have to use the 'set' method to update the value. Check the [link](https://www.telerik.com/forums/update-kendo-grid-cell-value-on-button-click#mJLzuse6hk-bfhLV9NSyEw)

If you provide better image of the grid and more explanation we might be able to help further.

You can use the 'save' function of the grid to call the function in the previous link instead of click. There is an [example](http://jsbin.com/exageg/6/edit?js,output)

```
var grid = $("#grid").kendoGrid({
    dataSource: dataSource,
    pageable: true,
    height: 430,
    toolbar: ["create"],
    columns: [
      "ProductName",
      { field: "UnitPrice", title: "Unit Price", format: "{0:c}"},
      { field: "UnitsInStock", title:"Units In Stock"},
      { field: "Discontinued"}, 
      ],
    editable: true,
    save: function(data) {     
      data.model.set("ProductName", "New Name");

    }
  }).data("kendoGrid");
});
```

Comment: Thanks, I tested the jsbin provided in the forum, my event is fired from the input itself, noclick event for my case, do you have any idea how can I achieve the same?

Comment: When do you want to validate? I've added more explanation.